# jQuery Animate Causing Element to Jump Down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfTXr/) where I am trying to create a "drawer" with jQuery. But for some odd reason my text is jumping down a few pixles when I am animating the slide. I can't quite seem to figure out what's causing it.

I just have two `inline-block` elements and I am attempting to hide/show one of them.

```
<div id="hover-me">
<div class="inline-block" id="show">
    Hello
</div>
<div class="inline-block">
    World
</div>
</div>

$("#hover-me").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(":first").animate({width:'toggle'},650);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Make it `float:left` like this, http://jsfiddle.net/LfTXr/1/

When you use `animate`, the function first removes the element from its position and applies the right/left movement.

When you `float` the element, its actually not on the screen, its floating and therefore the animation seems smooth.

Read more on position-property here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

```
.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height:10px; // <
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this does?